# typedef syntax with member function pointers

Tags: c++, typedef

according to MSDN the typedef syntax is:

> **typedef type-declaration synonym;**

Very easy:

```
typedef int MY_INT;
```

But how the heck does the member-function-pointer typedefs comply to this rule?

```
typedef int (MyClass::*MyTypedef)( int);
```

100% confusion – the synonym (`MyTypedef`) is in the middle?

Can someone please explain what the logical steps are to get from the very easy to understand syntax format of MSDN to the reverse/random/front/last/mixed syntax thing of aboves typedef?

*edit thanks for all the fast answers (and the beautification of my post) :)

Comment: It doesn’t – the MSDN is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, MSDN is wrong. `int typedef MY_INT` has the same meaning!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> the synonym (MyTypedef) is in the middle??

Its not in the middle.  Just forget member-function for a while, see how a function pointer is defined:

```
int (*FuncPtr)(int);
```

And this is how you would typedef it:

```
typedef int (*FuncPtr)(int);
```

Simple! The only difference is, in the typedef `FuncPtr` becomes a *type*,  while in the pointer declaration, `FuncPtr` is a *variable*.

Similarly,

```
int (MyClass::*MyTypedef)( int); //MyTypedef is a variable
```

And the typedef as:

```
typedef int (MyClass::*MyTypedef)( int); //MyTypedef is a type!
```

Comment: I think that the position of the `*` is the confusing part, so it may be worthwhile to remind that prefix "declaration operators" are right-associative, so the declaration is evaluated as "MyTypedef is a `pointer-to` `MyClass's` `function taking int` " etc.

Answer (score 41):

It's worth noting that, as of C++11, you could write this expression as a more legible `using` statement:

```
using MyTypedef = int (MyClass::*)(int);
```

Answer (score 11):

How do you define a pointer to member function? Like this:

```
int (A::*variableName)(int);
```

To make it a typedef, just add a typedef:

```
typedef int (A::*typedefName)(int);
```

Answer (score 5):

I know you've already got your answer, but want to share this - it's handy: http://www.cdecl.org. It's a C/C++ declaration <-> English translator. Just type in

> declare x as pointer to member of
>   class A function (int) returning char

and you get `char (A::*x)(int )`. Or play around with the declaration and see if you get what you want.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax of using member function pointer has to (assume `a` is an instance of class `A`):

- in declaration, use "A::" as prefix
- when use it, use "a." as prefix

Below is a toy example. You can play with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
class A;
typedef int (A::*F)(double);

class A {
 public:
  int funcDouble(double x) { return (int)(x * 2.0); }
  int funcTriple(double x) { return (int)(x * 3.0); }

  void set(int a) {
    if (a == 2) {
      this->f_ = &A::funcDouble;
    } else if (a == 3) {
      this->f_ = &A::funcTriple;
    } else {
      this->f_ = NULL;
    }
  }

 public:
  F f_;
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  A a;
  a.set(2);
  F f = &A::funcDouble;
  printf("double of 1 = %d\n", (a.*f)(1));

  // Below is equivalent to:
  // F f2 = a.f_;
  // printf("double of 1 = %d\n", (a.*f2)(1));
  printf("double of 1 = %d\n", (a.*(a.f_))(1));

  a.set(3);
  printf("triple of 1 = %d\n", (a.*(a.f_))(1));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code is best words to explain!

Answer (score 4):

The principle for declaration in C++ is that they mimick the use.  If you want to use a pointer to member function pmf, you'll write:

```
(myVar.*pmf)(arg);
```

so to define a typedef for it, you write:

```
typedef int (MyClass::*pmf)(int);
```

adding the return type in head, replacing the variable by the type and arguments by their type.

Comment: +1 that's how I understand them! Unfortunately cannot always be applied (e.g. references).

Comment: Is there a way to use "(myVar.*pmf)(arg);" without the "myVar" object?

Answer (score 1):

I once read a nice explanation (but it's from [Expect C Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298) so I ymmv):

> In fact, a typedef has exactly the
>   same format as a variable declaration,
>   only with this extra keyword to tip
>   you off.
>
> Since a typedef looks exactly like a
>   variable declaration, it is read
>   exactly like one. Instead of the
>   declaration saying "this name refers
>   to a variable of the stated type," **the
>   typedef keyword doesn't create a
>   variable, but causes the declaration
>   to say "this name is a synonym for the
>   stated type."**

So there you have it. Imagine you're declaring a variable, stick `typedef` before it and voila, you have a new type. `MSDN` explanations are a mixed bag: I've read really god ones and downright bad ones.

Answer (score 1):

The page you are referring to is probably "[typedef Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05w82thz.aspx)". The simplistic "`typedef type-declaration synonim;`" syntax is just one of the many ways to use typedef. There is (probably) no simple and concise way to describe how typedef can be used. That is what the "[Typedef Declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x7sfztk.aspx)" MSDN page is for.

You will notice on this page something like:

```
declaration: 
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list opt ; 
declaration-specifiers: 
    storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers opt 
    type-specifier declaration-specifiers opt
    type-qualifier declaration-specifiers opt 
storage-class-specifier: 
    typedef
```

More details as to what declaration-specifiers and init-declarator-list can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttt561z3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

This is one rigorous way to understand all possible usages for "typedef".

What this page basically says is that "typedef" can be used before most valid declarations.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to understand when you start thinking like this:

Whenever you see a function like this:

```
TYPE foo(int arg1, int arg2);
```

You say that the type of foo is TYPE. So, the type of

```
int get_next_prime();
```

is int.

You can see that when you pass a function pointer as an argument to a function:

```
void register_callback(void (*ptr)(int));
```

In this case, you are passing a function of type void as an argument.

Now, when you see something like that:

```
typedef int (A::*typedefName)(int);
```

you are just saying that the variable (A::*typedefName)(int) (this is only one thing, not two, since it's a function pointer declaration) is actually of type int. From then on, the compiler will interpret A::*typedefName as a function of type int, that is, it returns an int value.

Hope it makes it less confusing.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but is the above explanation correct? I just find it hard to to say that the type of get_next_prime is int.