# c++ function ptr in unorderer_map, compile time error

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

i am trying to implements an unorderer_map that implements as mapped_type, i was watching some examples that implements these but i cannot make it work.
here is the code:

```
#include<string>
#include <unordered_map>
namespace Test
{
  class Example
  {
  public:
    Example()
    {
      auto aPair=std::make_pair("one",&Example::procesString);
      map.insert(aPair);
    }
    void procesString(std::string & aString)
    {

    }
    void processStringTwo(std::string & aString)
    {

    }
    typedef void(*fnPtr)(std::string &);
    std::unordered_map<std::string,fnPtr> map;
  };
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

I get this compile time error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'std::unordered_map, void (*)(std::basic_string&)>::insert(std::pair, void (Test::Example::*)(std::basic_string&)>&)'

Thx!

Comment: A pointer to member function is not the same as a pointer to a free function.

Comment: `fnPtr` needs to be a pointer to member function not just a pointer to function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265851/typedef-syntax-with-member-function-pointers

Comment: _"i am trying to implements an unorderer_map that implements as mapped_type, i was watching some examples that implements these but i cannot make it work"_ No idea what this means...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function pointer and a member function pointer are two different things.  You either need to add a free function to the map or you need to change the map to take a member function pointer instead.  If you want to take a member function pointer than you can use this:

```
typedef void(Example::*fnPtr)(std::string &);
```

Comment: Ew! `std::function` and `std::bind`, please... We're not in 1825 any more

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  it's true that it would be more elegant. Nevertheless it all depends how time critical the function is.  On my compiler, in optimized mode, a call to a pointer to a member function costs 3 nanosecs, whereas a call to a functor with binding to an object  costs 36 nanosecs...

Comment: @Christophe Please present your benchmarks! I'd be interesting in analysing them.