# Does std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function<void(std::string&) can hold only static functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

This is a continuation of this question [c++ function ptr in unorderer_map, compile time error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533797/c-function-ptr-in-unorderer-map-compile-time-error#30533797)

I was trying to use `std::function` instead function pointer, and I can insert function only if the functions are  static. otherwise I will get following error

> main.cpp:15:11: error: no matching member function for call to
>   'insert'
>
> ```
>   map.insert(std::make_pair("one",&Example::procesString));
> ```

```
#include<string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include<functional>

namespace Test
{
 namespace Test
{
  class Example
  {
  public:
    Example()
    {

      map.insert(std::make_pair("one",&Example::procesString));
    }
    static void procesString(std::string & aString)
    //void procesString(std::string & aString) -> compiler error 
    {

    }
    static  void processStringTwo(std::string & aString)
    {

    }

    std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function<void(std::string&)>> map;
  };
}
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, your `std::function` type is wrong. For a member function `Example::processString(std::string&)`:

```
std::function<void(Example*, std::string&)>
```

However, you can avoid this and "eat up" that `this` parameter by early binding:

```
using std::placeholders;
map.insert(std::make_pair("one", std::bind(&Example::processString, this, _1));
```

Now the only argument left unbound is the string reference, so the type can remain:

```
std::function<void(std::string&)>
```

Comment: Wasn't sure if you were cool with me just editing it in , so figured I'd comment. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @Barry: Cheers (FYI: wouldn't have minded; twas obviously just a minor oversight)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks to clarify it.