# What this parameter of 'class A' call is doing?

Tags: c++, embedded-linux

I am having a classes define as in `b.h`

```
class A{ 
public:
   void       (B ::*writeBlock)    ();
};
```

Other `class B` is defined as

```
class B{
public:
      A obj;
};
```

Use of this parameter of `class B` is used in `b.cpp` as

```
(this->*obj.writeBlock)();
```

Please provide the definition of this above call for the `writeBlock`.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. This cannot, possibly, compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typedef syntax with member function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265851/typedef-syntax-with-member-function-pointers)

Comment: B::writeBlock is a member function pointer.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "the definition of this above call"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean what is it's purpose and possible use, then it's a way to let different instances of `B` have different behaviour, depending on what their `obj` have been initialized to for their `writeBlock` member.

Class `A` stores as a member the address of a member function of class `B` to be used later. That is what `writeBlock` is: It's a [pointer to member function](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).

`writeBlock` must get initialised somewhere to point to a member function of `B`, that in this case, takes zero parameters and returns void.

Possible scenario is as follows:

```
class B
{
public:
    A obj;

    void DoWork()
    {
        (this->*obj.writeBlock)();
    }

    void Task1() { std::cout << "1"; };
    void Task2() { std::cout << "2"; };
};


B b1, b2;
b1.obj.writeBlock = &B::Task1;
b2.obj.writeBlock = &B::Task2;

b1.DoWork(); // prints 1
b2.DoWork(); // prints 2
```

Here, `b1` and `b2` look the same, but behave differently. That is the purpose of this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

*Your question is not very clear, but still whatever I could understand:*

B is composed of A object, and a function pointer `writeBlock` of A object is not initialized. Further you are trying to dereference an uninitialized pointer `writeBlock`, while making call through it, which is wrong.

So first initialize the `writeBlock` to a member function of class `B`, then try dereferencing it.

Note `B::*` means a member function of class `B`. So, `this->*obj.writeBlock` must resolve to one of B's member functions.

Comment: What may be the possible call.